# How does the type deduction work for string literals in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, type-deduction

In C++ if I have a generic function:

```
template <typename T>
void func(T& s)
{
    std::cout << "in generic\n";
    std::cout << typeid(s).name();
}
```

`T` will get deduced to `typeid(s).name()`.

But how come if I do:

```
func("test");
```

That generic function works, but this one doesn't:

```
void func(const char*& s)
{   
    std::cout << "in overloaded\n";
    std::cout << typeid(s).name();
}
```

I know that it'll work if I change `const char*&` to `const char*` or `const char* const&`in the overloaded function's signature, and that if I want to pass an argument to the overloaded function it must be non-temporary. I just don't understand what happened to `T&`, isn't it supposed to turn into `const char*&` after the deduction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals are arrays of const characters. So in the case of the template function called like this:

```
func("test");
```

`T` is deduced as `char const[5]`. And `s` is a reference to the string literal, and its type is `char const (&)[5]`. That is, a reference to an array of 5 const char.

Comment: and char const(&)[5] is an array of const references to char?

Comment: @paulpaul1076: No. It's a reference to an array of 5 const char. Subtle difference in wording, but quite important (for one thing, you can't have an array of references).

Comment: @0x499602D2: No. Pointer decay happens depending upon the destination type (it needs to be a pointer).  And the normal rules about function parameters (where types that look like arrays are actually not arrays, but pointers) do not apply to references to arrays.

Answer (score 4):

The type of `"test"` is `const char[5]`. When calling a function template and using an argument to deduce a parameter of reference type, the array-to-pointer conversion does *not* happen. So the generic function deduces `T` to be `const char[5]` - you can see that the output for `"test"` and for a `const char*` differs:

```
template<typename T>
void func(T& s){

    std::cout << "in generic\n";
    std::cout << typeid(s).name() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    func("test");
    const char *c = "test";
    func(c);
}
```

[GCC output:](http://ideone.com/2CCDjF)

```
in generic
A5_c
in generic
PKc
```

On the other hand, in the non-generic function, you want a reference to a non-const pointer to `const char`. However, as the type of `"test"` is `const char[5]`, it has to undergo the array-to-pointer conversion, which means that the resulting `const char*` is a *temporary* (an *rvalue*). As such, it cannot bind to a reference to non-const.

Comment: +1 an extension of gcc and clang, the pretty-function macro does an especially good job of exposing this with template parameters. [**see it live**](http://ideone.com/pZO23A)